# User can't change prepopulate lookup field

Tags: lookup

Onclick 'New opportunity' button under the account. We see 'Account Name' field prepopulate as in images below.[image]

My requirement is while clicking lookup button for account selection. It should show only the existing account or user cannot change the current populating account. If a user selects another account it should throw error. How can we achieve this?

Comment: does your users profile FLS allow him to change the value? have you tried setting it to read only?

Comment: No, we can not make it read-only fields, cannot create a new pagelayout.

Comment: why cant you set it up a s read only for those profiles/users? and why would you want to create a new pagelayout?

Comment: Read-only is not recommended. Can we have some other approach?

Comment: why is it that according to you Read-only is not recommended ?

Comment: Because that profile can update the field later but while creating it can't be changed.

Comment: sounds to me like this is mostly a bad design/requirement and a custom UI would be the only way to cope with your requirement

Comment: I agree with @glls, but this sounds to me like it may just be a *misunderstanding* in constructing the requirements. I would go back to my users/tech lead and try to clarify what the purpose is here.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to make the field read-only on the page layout. This will allow the account they clicked the button on to be selected, but will not allow it to be changed. There is no other way in the standard user interface to enforce the behavior you're looking for. If the field is not read-only, they can change the value. A validation rule/trigger/etc won't help, because you cannot detect what the original account was, or if they changed the value. The only other alternative is to write your own Visualforce page for the New Opportunity page.

Comment: Can we apply lookup filter on that field?

Comment: @RAHULSRIVASTAVA It wouldn't do any good; you can only filter based on *data* on the record or the related record. There'd be no way to specify a filter of "only the record the user was looking at."